# Git log, ambiguous argument

Tags: git

Assuming 3 commits

```
commit e824a9be48accc21da5907924a5f7a20c48447ed
commit 62f819bdfe38e6252a54f5aae47fbf150d4e3371
commit eb8f996f6797df717247f911040b7d597b386ec3
```

**Why would `git log 62f` be thought of ambiguous?**

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '62f': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

After all, `62f` uniquely identifies second commit

Comment: ls .git/objects/62/f* to find all objects which can be identified by 62f id and make sure there is no other commits.

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak, In this case there is only 1, but this was an interesting exercise. +1 for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git's message is misleading here. Although `62f` is not ambiguous, Git requires a short SHA1 to be [at least four characters long](http://progit.org/book/ch6-1.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the data behind a single commit, you should use `git show 62f819bd`. Also `62f` is too short to be considered unique. I think the standard is 4 characters minimum, I usually put down the first 8.